# How to read and edit all the /system files from TWRP without root?

Tags: twrp

I want to edit my hosts file(/system/etc/hosts)to block ads. I thought to boot from the recovery and edit it from using the Advanced/Terminal utility. I realised that I was root(the mark was #). I ran cd /system then I ran the ls command but the only visible file was the bin directory.
I tried to run cd etc but it didn't work.
How can I access them without root my device?

Comment: Did you mount your `/system` partition in read-write mode from the **Mount** tab?

Answer (score 2):

Go to mount and tick system. You should see the files now.